# Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

Need some help.

I am trying to Log into Flipkart and buy the first Iphone via selenium.

However, I am getting stuck in the below mentioned page

[https://www.flipkart.com/apple-iphone-6…/p/itmen2yynt6bz3gg…](https://www.flipkart.com/apple-iphone-6%E2%80%A6/p/itmen2yynt6bz3gg%E2%80%A6)

I tried to click on the Compare Checkbox, 16GB Button, Buy Now button and Add to cart Button , but all of the operations are giving unable to locate error.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

I have used Implicit wait as well as Expected Wait but neither wait.

I also check for iframes in the page, but that did not work either.

```
 @Test(priority = 3,enabled = true)
  public void inPage() throws InterruptedException {
      
      
    
     WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 100);
      
     wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.className("_2AkmmA _2Npkh4 _2kuvG8 _7UHT_c"))).click();
     
    
  }



PASSED: logIn
PASSED: search
FAILED: inPage
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.className: _2AkmmA _2Npkh4 _2kuvG8 _7UHT_c (tried for 100 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:95)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:272)
    at First.inPage(First.java:94)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:583)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:719)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:989)
    at
```

Comment: Rather than using a generic locator type (class here), Try using a more effective locator (like id, name, xpath, etc..). Make sure the element that you are trying to click is visible and enabled on the page.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @AppuMistr. I used Xpath and CSS as well but to no avail.To check their visibility,I used  the below mentioned code, but M getting "Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable" error

Comment: public void inPage() throws InterruptedException {
 
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 100);
   
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"container\"]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/ul/li[2]/form/button")));
  
 boolean enabled = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"container\"]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/ul/li[2]/form/button")).isEnabled();
boolean visible = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"container\"]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/ul/li[2]/form/button")).isDisplayed(); }

Comment: Does clicking on the first search result ( first iPhone link) takes you to a different tab? If so, switch to the new tab and perform the further actions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this suggestion, it worked for me. God Bless you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've observed that clicking on the first search result (first iPhone) is opening up a new tab, in that case you have to switch to the new tab and perform the further actions.

```
driver.get(
        "https://www.flipkart.com/search?q=iphone&sid=tyy%2C4io&as=on&as-show=on&otracker=AS_QueryStore_OrganicAutoSuggest_0_4&otracker1=AS_QueryStore_OrganicAutoSuggest_0_4&as-pos=0&as-type=RECENT&as-backfill=on");

By firstSearchResult = By.className("_3O0U0u");
driver.findElement(firstSearchResult).click();

Thread.sleep(1000);

String currentWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
Set<String> windows = driver.getWindowHandles();
for (String window : windows) {
    if (!window.equals(currentWindow)) {
        driver.switchTo().window(window);
    }
}

// I'm performing these three steps to set pin-code, as i'm not logging-in. You
// may not have to perform these three steps as you are already logged -in.
driver.findElement(By.id("pincodeInputId")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("pincodeInputId")).sendKeys("500081");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='_2aK_gu' and text()[contains(.,'Check')]]")).click();


By button = By.xpath("//button[text()[contains(.,'BUY NOW')]]");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(button));
driver.findElement(button).click();
```

Comment: Thanks Sir, this gave me the desired result

Answer (score 0):

Mistake you are doing is using spaces in classnames ie By.className("_2AkmmA _2Npkh4 _2kuvG8 _7UHT_c" --> This is incorrect.

```
        driver.get(
            "https://www.flipkart.com/apple-iphone-6-space-grey-32-gb/p/itmetmh3hfhnxtcj?pid=MOBETMH3ZYNDPVVC&srno=s_1_1&otracker=search&otracker1=search&lid=LSTMOBETMH3ZYNDPVVCO3WYBD&fm=SEARCH&iid=d9dfe6a7-d4c6-48b0-b4f2-2046c0033347.MOBETMH3ZYNDPVVC.SEARCH&ppt=sp&ppn=sp&ssid=ouj8l7jf740000001563304721353&qH=43a53d285ae7d271");

    WebElement addToCard = driver.findElementByClassName("_2AkmmA");
    System.out.println(" addToCard text is " + addToCard.getText());

    WebElement buyNowButton = driver.findElementByClassName("_2kuvG8");
    System.out.println(" buyNowButton text is " + buyNowButton.getText());
```

I got the texts correctly

Comment: Thanks for your reply @ArunNair. When I directly navigate to this page, I am able to click as required, problem occurs when I land in homepage,Log in, search Iphone,choose first option and then come to this page. Please Suggest